# MongoDB 3.0 - how do I check which storage engine is being used?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

I have MongoDB 3.0.0 running on a Digital Ocean droplet.  How can I tell which storage engine it is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it through db.serverStatus() on section storageEngine -
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#storageengine